# How to set up Emacs Tide to use auto-complete for completion instead of company-mode?

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, javascript

I installed **Tide** in Emacs, and found it is pretty useful for writing JavaScript code.

But one thing is that Tide has built-in support for **company-mode** to do completions. Since I am an **auto-complete** user, just wondering whether it is possible to have a way to make **Tide** work with **auto-complete**?

Both Tide and auto-complete are 3rd party packages.

Comment: It is a 3rd party package. The link is https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide.

Comment: Please put that info in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.